# Run shell script from java

Tags: java, shell, servlets

I have `sendmail` file that contains this script `echo "sample message" | /usr/bin/swaks --to email@gmail.com` I want to run it from java using this code :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sendmail");
Process p = pb.start()
```

but the email is not sent. Whats wrong and how can i fix this?

edit : running `./sendmail` is working, and the email is sent to my mail

Comment: Does running that command from the command line work properly on that same computer?

Comment: @Cripto i run it using `./sendmail` and the email is sent to my mail

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your java application is ending before the script finishes.

Try this:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./sendmail.sh");
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String readline;
    int i = 0;
    while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(++i + " " + readline);
    }
```

The above code should print out what your command prints which could help you debug. It also has the side effect of blocking until the script is finished.

If that works and you don't care about the output, you can do this:

```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./test.sh");
  Process p = pb.start();
  p.waitFor();
```

Comment: ok thanks i will tried it later, have some error now bcos another reason. will update it if it works

Comment: i don't know why but in my project this isn't work, but i tried to make new java file and tried this its works fine. now i stuck why in my project its not working

Comment: Hmm, can you share your project via github? I can take a look at it?

Comment: Or at the minimum, share the entire method where this code live!